# How does Groot write his name?

Tags: marvel, groot

What is Groot's "full" name? *(First, Middle, Last)*

For example, how would he write his name on a job application?

> a) First Name: **I**, Middle: **Am**, Last Name: **Groot**
>
> b) First: **I am Groot**, Middle: **I am Groot**, Last: **I am Groot**
>
> c) or just **Groot** for every field?

How does he write his name?

Comment: Why would he even need to. Instant hire. Bypass HR and their “process”.

Comment: *waiting for Valorum to quote a novelization*

Comment: Who says Groot can write? And, of course, since other characters (at least in the comics) can apparently correctly interpret "I am Groot" as whatever Groot was trying to communicate, if he can write, it's possible that it would come out in a more standard form.

Comment: Given that his problem is in his larynx, I'd say writing wouldn't be such an issue for him.

Comment: If this question is changed to just "What is Groot's full name?", using the job application as an example, it becomes a good fit for the site.

Comment: i don't see how this is opinion based as-it, it's asking a factual question with a factual answer. just because we may or may not _know_ the answer doesn't mean it's an opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Groot is (apparently) a [mononym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person). Presumably he would be, on the sort of form you're describing

> First Name: Groot.
> Surname: N/A

---

He is referred to as "*Groot*" (no surname) in the prison scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy*:

[image: Groot stands bending down looking into the screen; his arms are still growing back; the side of the screen shows various information about him, his name simply shows as "Groot"]

Comment: It would appear that his height is not properly measured in this arrest photo.

Comment: Yes, but is his name "Groot" or is that what everyone _thinks_ it is since that's all he can say? What if his name is "Johnson Michaeltown" and he can write that just fine?

Comment: @Möoz - I can't find any reference (in the comics, film novelisations, scripts) to him having another name than Groot. His re-born self is consistently called "Baby Groot"

Comment: @Möoz Rocket can understand Groot and still calls him Groot. I'd assume from that his name is likely to be Groot.

Comment: After realizing that Groot is a mononym I believe that this would be the correct answer combined with something along the lines from this https://www.quora.com/How-do-people-with-just-one-legal-name-a-mononym-fill-out-online-forms-that-ask-for-their-first-and-last-names

Comment: I don't know if Groot is really his name; as I understand it, every one of his species vocalizes the same three words. It's possible he _has_ no individual name, or that his name isn't something that can be vocalized. Still, as far as every other species is concerned, that's his "name" so this answer is the best we can do.